# Change number of connection to database generated by a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have generated a spring boot project using jHipster. I want to reduce the number of connections to the database so I have modified the application-prod.yml file by adding the maximumPoolSize tag like this

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password:
    maximumPoolSize: 2
```

But when I try deploying the application I have 10 connections to the database. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: wrong property... should be `spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize`.

Comment: Thanks, now it's works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spring Boot 1.4 the general properties have been reduced and moved to specific properties per `DataSource` provider (which is also explained in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) and the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#datasource-binding)).

So instead of using `spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize` you should be using `spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize`

For a list of properties see [the appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).